# Remove entry from a list containing keyword - nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I  have this code to read a txt file and check the entries for the searched keyword and delete this line. Which works fine, however if the keyword is not found it doesn't stop but continues and deletes the last line of the file.

I do not want it to do that but to stop if the keyword is not found on the list.

```
const fs = require ('fs');

fs.readFile('./test/test2.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw error;

    let dataArray = data.split('\n'); 
    const searchKeyword = 'UserJerome';
    let lastIndex = -1; 

    for (let index=0; index<dataArray.length; index++) {
        if (dataArray[index].includes(searchKeyword)) {
            lastIndex = index; 
            break; 
        }
    }

    dataArray.splice(lastIndex, 1); 

    const updatedData = dataArray.join('\n');
    fs.writeFile('./test/test2.txt', updatedData, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log ('Successfully updated the file data');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If index is negative in `splice`, it will begin that many elements from the end. So `x.splice(-1, 1)` starts one element from the end of `x` and deletes a single element.

```
const fs = require ('fs');

fs.readFile('./test/test2.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw error;

    let dataArray = data.split('\n'); 
    const searchKeyword = 'UserJerome';
    let lastIndex = -1; 

    for (let index=0; index<dataArray.length; index++) {
        if (dataArray[index].includes(searchKeyword)) {
            lastIndex = index; 
            break; 
        }
    }

    if (lastIndex !== -1) { // <-----------------------------------
       dataArray.splice(lastIndex, 1); 
    }
    const updatedData = dataArray.join('\n');
    fs.writeFile('./test/test2.txt', updatedData, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log ('Successfully updated the file data');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a backwards `for loop` (so we don't mess with the order of the array while looping) and execute the `slice` method inside of it.

```
const fs = require ('fs');

fs.readFile('./test/test2.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw error;

    let dataArray = data.split('\n'); 
    const searchKeyword = 'UserJerome';
    
    for (let index = dataArray.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        if (dataArray[index].includes(searchKeyword)) {
          dataArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    const updatedData = dataArray.join('\n');
    fs.writeFile('./test/test2.txt', updatedData, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log ('Successfully updated the file data');
    });
});
```